# Sesame server crash while running queries (Sesame Version - 2.7.13)

Tags: tomcat, sparql, sesame

When running sesame for a period of time, doing queries, periodically the server fails to respond and Tomcat is getting down or crash.

I have uploaded DBPedia infobox ttl file to sesame server on linux machine. It worked very well for few days. After that server is not responding for any queries. When I shutdown tomcat it gives me below log info :

```
[localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload Waiting for 2 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [openrdf-http-server]
```

There are no logs for failure in tomcat as well as in aduna's openrdf-sesame logs.

Can somebody will help me to figure out the reason for failure?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer this. Is there a pattern to when it becomes unresponsive (are you executing a particular query or update before the crash)? You're saying there's no errors in the logs, but what _do_ the logs show? Is CPU / memory usage up? What kind of database are you using? It seems hard to believe that both Sesame _and_ Tomcat crash without any error in either the sesame or tomcat logs.

Comment: Also this: Sesame 2.7.13 is quite an old version. Not saying it will magically solve the problem but you could consider upgrading to the latest version of Sesame (4.0.1, or 2.8.8 if you're stuck on Java 6 compatibility).

Comment: Thanks Jeen, I will update to sesame 4.0.1 and try with it. Also there may be problem with memory, because after some queries I got hs_err_pid76273.log file in tomcat/bin which says "insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue".

Comment: Right, well, I'd say that's rather a giveaway ☺ Memory management of the query engine has improved in the newer releases ,  but it's still likely you need to assign more heap space to the tomcat JRE.